Getting rid of square root in $\sqrt{1 + \tan x}$
Is it possible to get rid of square root in
$\sqrt{1 + \tan x}$ ?
This can be done, for instance, for $\sqrt{1 + \cos x} = \left|\sqrt2 \cos \dfrac{x}{2}\right|$,
but I cannot come up with anything for tangent..

I hope this is not so nonsense and not takes downvotes...
For all $x\in[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2)$,
$$\sqrt{1+\tan x}=\sqrt[4]2\frac{\cos\arcsin\sqrt2\sin(\tfrac x2-\tfrac\pi8)}{\cos\arcsin\sqrt2\sin\tfrac x2}$$
And for $x\in[\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{3\pi}2)$, apply the same formula by setting $x:=x-\pi$.
We obtain this formula in two steps.

$$\sqrt{1+\tan x}=\sqrt{\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2(\cos x \cos\tfrac\pi4+\sin x\sin\tfrac\pi4)}{\cos x}}=\sqrt[4]2\sqrt{\frac{\cos(x-\tfrac\pi4)}{\cos x}}$$
For any $\theta\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$,
$$\sqrt{\cos\theta}=\sqrt{1-2\sin^2\frac\theta2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2v}=|\cos v|=\cos\arcsin\sqrt2\sin\frac\theta2$$
since $\sin v=\sqrt2\sin\frac\theta2$ and $v=\arcsin\sqrt2\sin\frac\theta2.$


Bob, it is not necessary to use absolute values in your formula because $\color{brown}{\cos(\arcsin t)\geqslant0}$ for any $t\in[-1,1]$, moreover your formula does not work on the intervals $\left[\frac{3\pi}4+2k\pi,\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi\right[$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z,.;$

Bob, the formula $\color{brown}{\sqrt{1+\tan x}=\sqrt[4]2\sqrt{\frac{\cos(x-\frac\pi4)}{\cos x}}}$ does work on any interval where $\sqrt{1+\tan x}$ is defined.

@Angelo I just used the traditional rule $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ over the real numbers. If we consider multi-valued $\arcsin$, I think absolute-value makes sense. For the domain restriction, maybe we can think of complex values.

@BobDobbs, the function arcsin is not multi-valued and you do not need to use a multi-valued function to get the value of $v$. Please, get a formula without square roots which does work on the intervals $\left[\frac{3\pi}4+2k\pi,\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi\right[.;$

@Angelo I did some improvement, I guess. But, I am bored of this question. :(

@BobDobbs, thank you very much for the improvement. I have just upvoted your answer.
